# my code do my print statement for many times ,I want to do it just for one time

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, printing

```
class LunarYear:
    def leap_year(self):
        for remaining in [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 22, 26, 30]:
            if self % 33 == remaining:
                print("leap year confirmed.")
                break
            else:
                print("leap year declined.")


LunarYear.leap_year(self=1395)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```py
class LunarYear:
    def leap_year(self):
        leap_year_remainders = [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 22, 26, 30]
        return self % 33 in leap_year_remainders # Returns True or False

outputs = {True: 'leap year confirmed', False: 'leap year declined'}
print(outputs[LunarYear.leap_year(self=1395)]) # Output: leap year confirmed
```

Or following your original idea:

```py
class LunarYear:
    def leap_year(self):
        for remaining in [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 22, 26, 30]:
            if self % 33 == remaining:
                print("leap year confirmed")
                break
        else:
            print("leap year declined")


LunarYear.leap_year(self=1395) # Output: leap year confirmed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the str in a variable and print it in the end.

```
class LunarYear:
def leap_year(self):
    msg = ""
    for remaining in [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 22, 26, 30]:
        if self % 33 == remaining:
            msg = "leap year confirmed."
            break
        else:
            msg = "leap year declined."

    print(msg)
```

Thus it will print only once.

Answer (score 0):

it will print 'leap year declined' twice and when the condition is true when it's equal to 9 it will print 'leap year confirmed.'
so you need to move else statement out from for loop

```
 for remaining in [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 22, 26, 30]:
        if self % 33 == remaining:
            print("leap year confirmed.")
            break
 else:
        print("leap year declined.")
```